# How do I change apps logins to ask for my username and password instead of root?

Tags: permissions, root, synaptic, gdebi

When I try to use Synaptic (or Gdebi) I'm asked for a password. The app lists the Identity: as "root" (with no way to change it). My (administrator) password fails.

I can use the app via the command line (`$ sudo synaptic`).

Comment: You should also be asked for a password when using the shell command. It seems like you are describing some kind of password pr account-permission issue, but you are instead asking about "app logins". How confusing. Keep in mind that we cannot see what you are seeing -- you must be our eyes. Please edit your question to explain the problem more clearly, and try to ask a single answerable question.

Comment: Also indicate the Ubuntu version on which you are seeing this.

Comment: When I start Synaptic (through the bucky key, bringing up Gnome's Activity overview overlay, then typing the first few characters of "Syna" then hitting enter), the "Authentication Required" window pops up. But it is displaying **my normal user**, and requesting my normal user's password. Why does yours ask for root at that point? That seems to be an anomaly, that would worth exploring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch Synaptic with your user password open the terminal and type:

```
pkexec synaptic
```

Then type your password in the Authentication Required window that pops up. One way that Ubuntu tells new users about the Authentication Required window is that the Software Updater uses it to authenticate pending software updates. GParted also uses the Authentication Required window for authentication when a user types the `gparted` command.

By default members of the `sudo` group and the root user are allowed to gain root privileges with pkexec.

As a security policy and to prevent file corruption, in general you shouldn't use sudo to open graphical applications as root.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to each of you for responding. It wasn't a well worded question and @user535733's point about logging in vs permissions is well taken. In any case ...

I eventually found someone asked basically the same question, [Gparted and Synaptic ask for root password instead of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470382/gparted-and-synaptic-ask-for-root-password-instead-of-mine), on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Although I'm still not certain about everything that's going on, setting a root password circumvented the issue for now. I will continue learning!

Comment: You shouldn't be running GUI applications as root. A quick search of this site will lead you to many people who have wrecked their OSes that way.